# My tutorial code to knockback an enemy does not work because of move_toward

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I was watching a tutorial and I followed the code the same as in the video, but the tutorial is for godot 3.2 and being on godot 4 it does not work when attacking the enemy and I get an error that says:
Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'move_toward' in base 'bool'.
This is the code:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

var knockback = Vector2.ZERO

func _physics_process(delta):
    knockback = knockback.move_toward(Vector2.ZERO, 200 * delta)
    knockback = move_and_slide(knockback)

func _on_hurtbox_area_entered(area):
    knockback = Vector2.RIGHT * 200
```

I tried to delete the move_and_slide arguments and tried to change the move_toward to move_and_slide but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that `move_and_slide` returns `bool` (`true` if it collided, `false` if it didn't).

Thus, here:

```
knockback = move_and_slide()
```

The `knockback` variable becomes a `bool`. Thus, next frame, when you try to do this:

```
knockback = knockback.move_toward(Vector2.ZERO, 200 * delta)
```

Godot can't call `move_toward` on a `bool`, and give you an error.

---

You would have gotten the error earlier if you make `knockback` a typed variable, which would be explicitly like this:

```
var knockback:Vector2 = Vector2.ZERO
```

Or implicitly (with inference) like this:

```
var knockback:= Vector2.ZERO
```

---

Furthermore, as you know, in Godot 4 `move_and_slide` no longer takes a velocity, instead you are supposed to set the `velocity` property. Which means, you could make away with not having a `knockback` variable.

The code would be like this:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity = velocity.move_toward(Vector2.ZERO, 200 * delta)
    move_and_slide()

func _on_hurtbox_area_entered(area):
    velocity += Vector2.RIGHT * 200
```

Here the line using `move_toward` is performing deceleration.

Presumably you will have other code manipulating `velocity`, thus double check if you are not doing deceleration already (in which case you do not need to do it here), and if adding deceleration do not mess with anything else.

Comment: No me importa que no se supone que deba dar gracias pero acabo de abrir esta cuenta y no me importa GR4CIAS!!!!!!!

Comment: @DaPOPs And apparently you do not care that you are supposed to write English :v - Anyway, I'm glad this answer is useful.

Comment: I used this code and my enemy teleports instead of being "knocked back." Any suggestions?

Comment: @Anon214 You haven't told me if there is a pattern to the teleportation. However, this is the first to come to mind: if the direction is correct, make the speed lower (not `200` but much less). In particular if you are doing his in 3D, unlike this question which is for 2D. Also, I'll reiterate this form my answer: "Presumably you will have other code manipulating `velocity`"... perhaps adding this code messes with it in some unexpected way.

Comment: My apologies for being vague. I set the direction of my enemy to Vector2.RIGHT and it teleports based upon how much I multiply by it. For example, velocity += Vector2.RIGHT * 5000 teleports way further than velocity += Vector2.RIGHT * 500. I am doing this in 2D. Now that you mention there could be other velocity factors, I have a state machine that increases enemy.velocity by direction.noramlized() * move_speed as well. Thank you for the suggestion, I will look into that.